# port 3306 continues to close, no access to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Mac running Mavericks with MySQL installed from [homebrew](http://brew.sh).  When I try `nmap localhost` and I see:

```
3306/tcp open mysql
```

When I try this same command with my computer name:

```
nmap my_comp_name
```

I do not get `3306` but I get:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
3128/tcp open  squid-http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

It also says my computer name resolves to some ip address.  When I try `nmap` with that ip address, I get the same response as above.  I want to be able to connect to this database with Visual Studio running on my Parallels VM.

This happened some time yesterday and I finally figured out that Norton anti virus was installed blocking that port.  So I uninstalled Norton with one of their scripts and restarted.  Everything was working fine at work, and then I came home and again, the port is closed.

I do not have a firewall on for either my Mac or Windows (Parallels VM) machine.  I cannot figure out why this port gets closed.  I do not have a firewall set up on my home network either.  This port has been opened in the past on my home network as well.  I am at a loss of figuring out what is causing this port to just suddenly close without even rebooting my computer.  I basically come home, and port `3306` is now closed.  Any thoughts?

Edit: I have also tried adding `port = 3306` in the my.cnf file, restarted apache, and that also does not solve my problem.

Comment: What do the MySQL logs show?

Comment: @AzizSaleh Where can I find those?

Comment: This seems like a binding problem. It seems like it is binding to your private ip instead of all or 127.0.0.1/localhost. But that is just from the top of my head.

Comment: @Crystal can you check your `/etc/my.cnf` and find the line `bind-address`? what does it contain?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and belongs on [su].

Answer (score 3):

When you run nmap against localhost it uses IP address 127.0.0.1. When you run it against your hostname, it uses the 'real' IP address of your host.

Clearly you have MySQL configured to bind only on IP address 127.0.0.1, and need to change the config to bind to all addresses if you want to access MySQL from a different host (even if the host is running in a VM inside your machine).

Find the file `/etc/my.cnf` and see if it contains a line like

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

If it does, remove it or change it to

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

If `my.cnf` does not contain a line binding to 127.0.0.1, then you may have to find the script that starts MySQL and examine it to see how it sets the bind address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create or edit my.cnf

Open mysql launch file

```
vi ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

And change this line

```
<string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>
```

to

```
<string>--bind-address=0.0.0.0</string>
```

And finally reload MySQL

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a binding problem. It seems like it is binding to your private ip instead of all or 127.0.0.1/localhost. But that is just from the top of my head.

From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html):

> The MySQL server listens on a single network socket for TCP/IP
>   connections. This socket is bound to a single address, but it is
>   possible for an address to map onto multiple network interfaces. The
>   default address is 0.0.0.0. To specify an address explicitly, use the
>   --bind-address=addr option at server startup, where addr is an IPv4 address or a host name. If addr is a host name, the server resolves
>   the name to an IPv4 address and binds to that address. The server
>   treats different types of addresses as follows:
>
> If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on
>   all server host IPv4 interfaces. If the address is a "regular" IPv4
>   address (such as 127.0.0.1), the server accepts TCP/IP connections
>   only for that particular IPv4 address.

**Configuration**

You can set bind-address directive in `my.cnf`. Edit `/etc/my.cnf` or `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`, run:

```
$ nano /etc/my.cnf
```

Set the address to `0.0.0.0`:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Make sure you delete the following line or comment out the following line:

```
#skip-networking
```

Save and close the file.

Finally **restart the mysql service**.

[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/).